# Failable Constructors with "strictNullChecks" compiler option

Tags: typescript

I like the idea of using `strictNullChecks` option in Typescript for better and more explicit `null`/`undefined` handling. But I can't find a way to achieve a *"Failable Constructor"* pattern with `strictNullChecks` enabled.

Usually a default `strictNullChecks` is the desired behavior, but sometimes returning `undefined` from a constructor makes sense and the code is more readable and flexible, as opposed to throwing an error when the object can't be created.

With regular function types, this can be explicitly allowed by adding `undefined` to the function's return type. But Typescript doesn't allow setting the return type of a constructor.

Is there any way to enable `strictNullChecks` and still have the ability for constructors to return `undefined` in some cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript does no support type annotations for the return type of a constructor in a class.

You can declare the class and define the constructor separately as returning `InstanceType | undefined`.

```
class _X {
    constructor() {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) return undefined as any;
    }
}

const X = _X as MakeFailable<typeof _X>;

type MakeFailable<T extends new (...a: any[]) => any> = {
    new (...a: ConstructorParameters<T>): undefined | InstanceType<T>
} & Pick<T, keyof T>
```

One problem is that the class obtained this way will not be inheritable since typescript can't deal with the `undefined` in the return of the constructor.

You could even make a helper function to better hide the implementation class:

```
type MakeFailable<T extends new (...a: any[]) => any> = {
    new (...a: ConstructorParameters<T>): undefined | InstanceType<T>
} & Pick<T, keyof T>

function makeFailable<T extends new (...a: any[]) => any>(cls: T): MakeFailable<T> {
    return cls as any
}

const Foo = makeFailable(class {
    constructor() {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) return undefined as any;
    }
})
type Foo = InstanceType<typeof Foo>
```

Comment: Thanks. I suspected that the workaround might be cumbersome. FWIW, I opened [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29893) for this. I'll accept this answer if nothing more elegant comes up.